# Is there any simple and fast way to tell whether a git repo has used LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to set up my env and install git-lfs only if it is necessary based on whether there is a file in the repo that uses LFS.

Is there a lightweight, fast, and easy way to check it?

Answer (score 2):

This command will show all lfs files

```
git lfs ls-files
```

Comment: The question was how to know whether the repo is using LFS for any of its files. This answer seems to be in the right direction but a bit incomplete.

Comment: I cannot comment @jthill answer due to reputation score. His answer is better for your case. But it's also a bit incomplete. `.gitattributes` could be located in subdirectories too. So the right command will be:

`git grep -q filter=lfs -- **/.gitattributes && echo is || echo isn\'t`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know whether a project is *currently* set up for lfs,

```
if git grep -q filter=lfs -- .gitattributes '**/.gitattributes'
then echo is
else echo isn\'t
fi
```

will answer fast.

To check whether a project has *ever* used lfs, fastest way I can think of is

```
while read
do
    if git grep -q filter=lfs $REPLY -- .gitattributes '**/.gitattributes'
    then git lfs install; break
    fi
done <<EOD
$(git rev-list --all --diff-filter=d -- .gitattributes '**/.gitattributes')
EOD
```

. . . the quirky while read … done <<EOD setup is to keep the loop in the main shell so variable updates in the loop persist, it's all the same variables. This one doesn't do any and a more *compact* way would be

```
git rev-list --all --diff-filter=d -- .gitattributes '**/.gitattributes' \
| while read; do
        if git grep -q filter=lfs $REPLY -- .gitattributes '**/.gitattributes'
         then git lfs install; break
         fi
done
```

(edit: [thanks @Ivan Onushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335964/is-there-any-simple-and-fast-way-to-tell-whether-a-git-repo-has-used-lfs/76197696#comment134396729_76163999) for catching the nested-attributes case `.gitattributes '**/.gitattributes`')

Answer (score -3):

found an easy way. just check whether '.git/objects' folder exists

Comment: `.git/objects` exists for every Git repos irrespective of Git LFS being used or not.

Comment: I think you might have typoed `.git/lfs/objects`, which still won't be there on a fresh clone that needs lfs but doesn't have it yet.